# $ P(|\mathcal{N}(0,1)| >k) \leq e^{-k}$

Tags: probability-distributions

- $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$
- $ k \geq 2$
- We want to prove that $ P(|X| >k) \leq e^{-k}$

---

My attempt :

$
\begin{align*}
P(|X| >k) & =P( e^{ |X|  } > e^k ) \\
&\leq e^{-k} E( e^{|X|} ) \\
&= e^{-k} \int_{0}^{ \infty} \dfrac{2}{ \sqrt{2 \pi} }e^{-t} e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}  }dt \\
&= e^{-k} \int_{0}^{ \infty} \dfrac{2}{ \sqrt{2 \pi} } e^{ -\frac{(t+1)^2-1 }{2} }dt\\
\end{align*}
$

Comment: Do you want $k \leq 2$ or $k \geq 2$?

Comment: That integral is the moment generating function of the folded normal distribution.

Comment: How do I compute it from scratch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's proceed as follows. With your notations, by symmetry, it suffices to show that $$\mathbb{P}(X > k) \leq \frac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-k}$$ holding for each $k>2$. Let's define the function $$\Phi \,\colon y \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}}\int_y^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}x,$$ so it suffices to show that $\Phi(k) < \frac{1}{2}\,\mathrm{e}^{-k}.$ In general, we will show that $$\Phi(y) < \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}\,y}\mathrm{e}^{-y^2/2}$$ for each $y > 0$. Indeed, by the definition of $\Phi$, we have $$\Phi(y) \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}} \int_y^\infty \tfrac{x}{y}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}\,y}\mathrm{e}^{-y^2/2}.$$ Can you conclude from there?

Comment: Remark: A very similar approach yields a lower bound as well, meaning that for each $y > 0$, we will have $$\Phi(y) \geq \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}\,(y+1)}\left(\mathrm{e}^{-y^2/2} - \mathrm{e}^{-(y+1)^2/2}\right).$$ Combing these yields the asymptotic equivalence $$\Phi(y) \sim \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\,\pi}\,y}\mathrm{e}^{-y^2/2}$$ for all large $y$.

Comment: $ \Phi(y) \geq \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{ 2 \pi }} \int_{y}^{y+1} x e^{ -\frac{x^2}{2}}$

Comment: Thanks so much.